# Netbeans debugger doesn't load manifest.mf?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, manifest

I'm developing a java desktop application. When it's compiled into a Jar file and run, the code has access to its embedded Manifest file.

However, although i've put my netbeans.properties and manifest content correctly(so that the manifest ends up in the Jar file), while running in Debug mode the manifest just isn't available.

I've tried cycling through all available manifest files using getResources(), but it just isn't there. It doesn't seem to end up in the /build folder as wel. Any ideas?

(using Netbeans 8) Appreciate it

`is this such a difficult problem? it's so quiet here :(`